# Closed source project migration from jcenter to maven central

Tags: android, bintray, jcenter, maven-central

Since JCenter is shutting down on 1 May 2021. What are other options to publish a closed source library?. I have searched online but have not been able to get any reliable and recent information on this.

- What are the options available for my company to offer closed source libraries/binaries via maven central? The libraries are free to use by anyone.
- If there's any way to distribute the artifact in maven central without distributing the source code. What is more suitable for closed source projects, please help me to provide the right way to publish the closed source project in maven central.

Comment: "What are other options to publish a closed source library?" -- host it yourself in your own Maven repo. For example, my now-mostly-defunct CWAC libraries are hosted on Amazon S3. Consumers of the libraries have to add my repository to their Gradle setup in addition to having the dependency, but it is only a couple of additional lines. See the code snippet at the top of https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security for an example of what library consumers would need to do.

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching a lot and found this Maven Central ticket, that says that producers are available to distribute free of charge closed source libraries.

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-692